# ADC Clamping Rrotection Circuit with Dual serial Diodes - Formula proof

Tags: diodes, adc, circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection, diode-clamp

I am trying to undestand and calculate why in the first circuit we measure 5.7Volt (if forward noltage diode is 0.7Volt) and not 12V. I used the Superposition Theorem which first I replaced the Vcc source with ground and calulate the Vr1 and then I replaced the V1 source with ground and I calculate the Vr1 again. Finally I add the two voltages that I found but the result is not match with expect result. Does any know's with which law/rule the circuit can be prooven mathematically? Also something that I noticed one the simulation program (multisim) is when I decrease the R1 the Vr1 increases and when I increase the R1 the Vr1 decreases.

With Vcc replaced with GND the Vr1a is: 0.7V (D1 is biased and parallel with R1)

With V1 replaced with GND the Vr1b is: 0V (D1 is not biased)

Total Vr1 = Vr1a + Vr1b = 0.7V + 0V = 0.7V

[image]

Comment: Reverse the top diodes ! If you want 12V then add a divider in between

Answer (score 1):

Drawing the circuit differently may help:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcG5y6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much... this redesign will make it so simple. By applying the Kirchhoff's voltage law (second) we have: Because the V1 is the higher voltage the current will flow from V1 to V2 and so... V1=Vr1+Vd1+Vd2 - > 12V=Vr1+0.7V+5V -> Vr1=12V-0.7V-5V=6.3V... Vadc_chip=Vd1+V2=0.7V+5V=5.7V

Answer (score 0):

Superposition is only valid for **linear** systems. Diodes are not linear!

To solve this (more) exactly you need to use the [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation). For a rough estimate, when the diode is conducting it has 0.7V across it.

In a real circuit, the regulator supplying the +5V rail may offer little or no ability to sink current so the clamp may be rather ineffective on the positive side.